# netlogo: how to get nodes that are connected with a link to a node N

Tags: netlogo

i'm trying to simulate a collaborative decision making in Netlogo, and i've a network of nodes connected links, so what i want to do is to be able to get all nodes that are connected with a given node N. 
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`link-neighbors`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#link-neighbors) primitive. There are also directed variants as well: `in-link-neighbors` and `out-link-neighbors`.